# Why is so common to see internal function calls from (seemingly) useless wrapping external functions?

Tags: visibility

Many times I see this type of architecture within a smart contract:

```
function mint(uint256 amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint tokens");
    _mint(amount);
}

function _mint(uint256 amount) internal {
    //minting logic
}
```

Why not just making the `_mint()` function external and move the `require()` line into that function?

Answer (score 0):

Making things easier to read. Here is the example from the contract I wrote:

```js
function unstake(uint256 _cid, uint256 _id) external {
        _unstake(msg.sender, _cid, _id);
    }
```

```js
function _unstake(
        address _user,
        uint256 _cid,
        uint256 _id
    ) internal {
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_user];
        CollectionInfo storage collection = collectionInfo[_cid];

        require(
            tokenOwners[collection.collectionAddress][_id] == _user,
            "Masterdemon._unstake: Sender doesn't owns this token"
        );

        user.stakedTokens[collection.collectionAddress].removeElement(_id);

        if (user.stakedTokens[collection.collectionAddress].length == 0) {
            collection.amountOfStakers -= 1;
        }

        delete tokenOwners[collection.collectionAddress][_id];

        user.timeStaked[collection.collectionAddress] = block.timestamp;
        user.amountStaked -= 1;

        if (user.amountStaked == 0) {
            delete userInfo[_user];
        }

        IERC721(collection.collectionAddress).transferFrom(
            address(this),
            _user,
            _id
        );
    }
```

Wrote this way to kinda classify the "frontend, external" function and "backend, internal" function. Makes code easier to read IMHO. Just the way I prefer to write I guess, other than that, I don't see any other reason to split function that way. Perhaps there are some very, very specific cases, but I can't recall any of that ATM.